# Не пойму логику создания фрагмента после пересоздания activity

Tags: android

Есть активити. layout для неё создаётся руками в onCreate активити. Сперва создаю экземпляр фрагмента, а потом:

```
// ctx - это активити
FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(ctx); 
fl.setId(R.id.id13);

FragmentTransaction tr = ctx.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    
tr.replace(R.id.id13, fragment);
tr.commit();
```

Всё создаётся корректно. Теперь жму HOME, останавливаю приложение (через adb shell: su -c 'killall ').
Снова запускаю приложение.
Но почему создаётся мой фрагмент без параметров (ctor()), если я не сделаю повторно replace фрагмента?

Вот кусок самого кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

onCreateInternal() - это считайте Activity::onCreate().

Comment: Из кода не видно, как вы сам фрагмент создаете.

Comment: о каких параметрах идет речь?

Comment: Наверно, что-то не понимаю :) Создаю через new MyFragment(...). Без параметров -  я имею ввиду, что ctor без параметров. Т.е. у меня у фрагмента есть 2 конструктора. Один с параметрами - который я вручную создаю в активити и второй без параметров - который я сам никогда не создаю, но его андроид создаёт через рефлекшен. Сейчас немного первый пост подредактирую